# Cannot resolve symbol 'validator' while using android library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, validation, android-library

I want to use this library - https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar for form validation in my android app

I have included the dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
}
```

I also added this to the build.gradle project (app)

```
maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
```

I added all the codes required in the library but when I add this line of code:

```
validator = new Validator(this);
validator.setValidationListener(this);

......
validator.validate();
```

in super.OnCreate method in my activity

I get this error -

**Cannot resolve symbol 'validator'**

**error: cannot find symbol variable validator**

I have tried to clean project and rebuild project, its not working.

Comment: what data type you use for validator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the proper example they have provided in [github](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/blob/master/saripaar-tests/src/main/java/com/mobsandgeeks/saripaar/tests/ui/OptionalActivity.java#L31).

```
Validator validator = new Validator(this);
validator.setValidationListener(this);

validator.validate();
```